# install specific version of pupppet on Fedora 23

Tags: linux, puppet, redhat, yum, fedora-23

How do I install specific version(3.0.2) of puppet and puppet-server on Fedora through dnf.
I am using "Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)"
When I install using yum it installs the latest version greater than 4.2.
 When I try to install using rpm I have to resolve many dependencies. It is tedious for me.

```
[root@puppet ~]# uname -a
Linux puppet 4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 5 15:42:54 UTC 2015  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@puppet ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three)
[root@puppet ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

There aren't going to be any compatible packages of Puppet 3.0 for Fedora 23, it's an incompatible combination as the Ruby version in Fedora 23 (Ruby 2.2) is unsupported by such an old version of Puppet ([docs](https://docs.puppet.com/guides/platforms.html#ruby-versions)).

To get anywhere, you'd probably have to either backport patches for compatibility or install an older version of Ruby. I wouldn't recommend this at all in your situation.

You should seriously reconsider what you're trying to do, as Puppet 3.0.2 is three years old, while Fedora 23 is less than six months old at the time of writing.  Both Fedora and Puppet Labs ship fully compatible packages for Puppet 4.  Also, Puppet 3.0.x was also an unreliable, early series of releases, it'd be preferable to use at least the latest 3.x.